# How can I implement a 2D skeletal animation system in my game?

Tags: c++, graphics, panda3d

Hey. I want to be able to create a system for skeletal animation in my game. I'm using [panda3d](http://www.panda3D.org) as my game engine. I'd like to be able to make simple bone structures and skin them with my sprites. I would prefer to do this with straight code and algorithms, but if I have to use a 3D modeler or something, then I can try to (I didn't do a great job last time I tried using Blender... >.<)

Comment: Should probably be asked here instead: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know about that until you said anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it just like you would in 3D, but diregarding depth coordinates.